# How do I load multiple programs in a Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file to load multiple Window programs, more specifically, applications that control peripheral flight hardware.

I can't seem to figure out how to open up all applications consecutively. I've tried a number of things including running the executable application:

```
@echo off
cd "D:\Controls\" & start "D:\HW_Controls\Control1.exe" &
cd "D:\Controls\" & start "D:\HW_Controls\Control2.exe" &
cd "D:\Controls\" & start "D:\HW_Controls\Control3.exe"
```

That would only run one application at a time, until I exit that application, which is what I don't want. I want them to open consecutively. So I read somewhere on StackOverflow from an old post to try running each application as its own batch file like so:

```
@echo off
start "D:\Controls1.bat" &
start "D:\Controls2.bat" &
start "D:\Controls3.bat"
```

In which each batch file within looks similar to this:

```
cd "D:\Controls\" & start "D:\HW_Controls\Control{1..3}.exe"
```

I've also tried using chdir:

```
chdir "D:\Controls\" & start "D:\HW_Controls\Control{1..3}.exe"
```

When I try to load the batch file within, it doesn't appear to change the directory, and loads only opens a command prompt where the initial batch file is located, in this case, the Desktop directory.

I know there are options to open them on Windows startup, but that's not what I want. I want to load them up when I need to use the applications.

BONUS POINTS: If someone can tell me how to exit all the applications in a batch script as well when I'm finished with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch parser works line by line. `&` is used to write two commands in one line. So it doesn't make sense to end a line with a `&`.

For readability, the use of `&` should be limited.

`cd` should be used with the `/d` switch to be able to switch to another drive.

`start` takes the first quoted parameter as a window title, so give it a pseudo title.

`start` has a `/d` parameter to set the working folder, so you don't need `cd` at all:

So your batch file simplifies to:

```
@echo off
start "" /d "D:\Controls\" "D:\HW_Controls\Control1.exe"
start "" /d "D:\Controls\" "D:\HW_Controls\Control2.exe"
start "" /d "D:\Controls\" "D:\HW_Controls\Control3.exe"
echo press any key to kill the program.
pause >nul
taskkill /im "Control1.exe"
taskkill /im "Control2.exe"
taskkill /im "Control3.exe"
```

Note: `taskkill` sends a termination signal to the application. If it does not answer correctly by closing itself, you can force-close it with the `/f` switch.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but I tried running it in a command prompt instead of a Windows icon, and when running the batch file, it says "The current directory is invalid.". But I can `cd` into the application directory listed in the application executable string.

Comment: read again. It's `start "title" /d "<folder>" "<program>"`. You did only `start "title" /d "<program>"` and consequently get "the current directory (`D:\...\....EXE`) is invalid - because it's not a directory.

Comment: Of course.. Sorry, can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method to launch multiple programs at once:

```
@For %%A in ("notepad.exe" "chrome.exe" "calc.exe") do start "" %%~A
```